# How to sequence events while uploading large files to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am seeing problems uploading large files e.g. 100MB. Files go to Amazon S3 successfully, but after that scripts are waiting for `if($flag == 1)` and do not execute the rest of the code. Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

```
if($s3->putObjectFile($uploadDIR, $bucket, $name, S3::ACL))
{
      $flag = 1;
}

if($flag == 1)
{
      //continue code
}
```

Comment: This is PHP Lanuage(ServerSide Scripting Language)

Answer (score 0):

Seems more of a case where there is a cap on the file size for a single put upload. Did you try doing a miltipart upload?

AWS forums suggest setting the threshold for a single part upload to 16MB limit (java sdk has this limit) and anything beyond this size is broken up into 5MB chunks to do multipart upload to make it easy on the memory.

Try this : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/upload_part